# AppleScript: How do I get get a file list of files in folder and remove extension from that list

Tags: macos, applescript

I have this code working just fine to get the list of scripts in the folder called Plugins. However, i'd like to display that list in the choose from list without the file extension displayed.

```
set scriptLocation to alias ((path to me as text) & "Contents:Resources")
tell application "Finder"

set filelist to name of every file in folder "Plugins" of scriptLocation whose name extension is "scpt"
end tell
set {TID, text item delimiters} to {text item delimiters, return}
set text item delimiters to TID



set returnedInfo to (choose from list {"Menu"} & "" & filelist)
```

The code is very big and I just put in the part of it that deals with getting the list of files and displaying it as a choose from list.

Answer (score 0):

You need a repeat loop

```
set scriptLocation to alias ((path to me as text) & "Contents:Resources:")

tell application "System Events"
    set filelist to name of every file in folder "Plugins" of scriptLocation whose name extension is "scpt"
end tell
repeat with aFile in filelist
    set contents of aFile to text 1 thru -6 of aFile
end repeat

set returnedInfo to (choose from list {"Menu"} & "" & filelist)
```